# Facebook progress dialog spinner when logging in Android application

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-login, progressdialog, facebook-sdk-3.1

Hi I want to customize my progress dialog box when the user clicks on facebook button to login. I am able to customize the dialog for google login but not in this case. I tried to change the WebDialog class in facebook sdk that I uploaded in my project but that changes are not showing up. So can anyone help me with that as o what needs to be done if we need to customize facebook spinner for logging in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952681/1435712) to hide the Facebook spinner, and then implement your own spinner to be displayed once the Facebook Login button is pressed.